# How to count the number of elements needed to get a certain sum?

Tags: probability-distributions, wolfram-alpha

I want to find $x$ in this equation:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^x\left[\left(1- {49\choose6}^{-1}\right)^{n-1} \times {49 \choose 6}^{-1}\right] \geqslant 0.5 $$
If I'm thinking correctly, that's the question of how many coupons should I buy, so my chance of winning would be at least $50\%$, providing I win by correctly choosing $6$ numbers out of $49$. The order of the numbers doesn't matter, no returns. My intention was to use the geometric distribution cumulative probability formula: $$\sum_{n=1}^k \left[(1-p)^{n-1} \times p\right] $$ where $ p = {49 \choose 6}^{-1} $. So what is the minimum $x$ with which my overall probability would be something close to $50\%$?

I don't want to calculate it by hand, Wolfram Alpha formula is enough for me. I just can't get it right, it always spits out something that is not my $x$. I also have a CASIO calculator but I doubt it can calculate that.

Comment: If you plug that sum into WolframAlpha, you'll find it's just a geometric series,and you can evaluate it explicitly. From there it should just be algebra and a single logarithm to find where it equals .5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a sum
$$S(n)=p\sum_{k=1}^n(1-p)^{k-1}$$
You can work out explicitly that
$$S(n)=1-(1-p)^n$$
See [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20geometric%20series,previous%20term%20by%201%2F2.). So
$$1-(1-p)^n>0.5$$
$$(1-p)^n<0.5$$
$$\log((1-p)^n)<\log(0.5)$$
$$n>\frac{\log(0.5)}{\log(1-p)}$$
$$n\geq \left\lceil\frac{\log(0.5)}{\log(1-p)}\right\rceil$$
If you can't be bothered with any of that, Python works too.

```
import math
def Binom(n,k):
    return math.factorial(n)/(math.factorial(n-k)*math.factorial(k))
p=1/Binom(49,6)
n=1
S=0
while (S<0.5):
    S+= p*(1-p)**(n-1)
    n+=1
print(n-1)
```

[Either way](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Ceil%5BLog%5B0.5%5D%2FLog%5B1-%281%2FBinomial%5B49%2C6%5D%29%5D%5D), the number you're looking for is

### $$n=9~692~843$$

Comment: Thank you, your answer has given me some insight about how can I use R to solve problems like this one. One thing bothers me though. Why should i print $n-1$ instead of $n$?

Comment: @JakubJędrusiak The way I wrote the code, the summation index `n` is actually one more than the number of terms I've added. Notice how after the first term is added, there is the `n+=1` command which sets the counter to `2`. You could probably rework the incrementation process to make it possible to just to `print(n)` but it took me about 60 seconds to write the code so I'm not really bothered to change it.